# Can you ride an RX train with a ticket for an R train?

Tags: trains, tickets, czech-republic

Via the internet site of German Rail I bought a train ticket for a ride with an `R` train between two cities in the Czech Republic.

Now I saw there is a different connection between the two cities I would rather take but this train is classified as `RX`.

Can I use the `RX` train with the ticket for the `R` train?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have an open ticket from Czech Railways (ČD / České dráhy), you can take any train category: Os, Sp, R, Rx, Ex, IC, EC, railjet/rj. For SC, you need a compulsory reservation.

Be aware of "SuperAkční jízdenka" which is a super-saver fare valid for selected train only.

There are also various other railway companies in Czechia like ARRIVA vlaky, GWTR, JHMD, KŽC, LEO Express, RegioJet, Trilex, Vogtlandbahn where ČD tikets are not valid unless noted explicitely.